# getting reliable informations about GPU memory under OpenGL ES

Tags: memory, opengl-es-2.0, gpu

How i can get reliable informations about the memory reserved for the GPU operations in an OpenGL ES environment ? For example how i can determine how much memory i can use to store textures ? There are APIs or a class of functions dedicated to memory inspection in OpenGL?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I just stumbled upon it, so I will answer.

You can use [glGetIntegerv](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml)  with GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE to know what your GPU allows.

No other memory inspection features, but you should query extensions, and system render buffer capabilities, and amount of data you can push for every feature.

Check in the same page the constants starting with GL_MAX_

With 'modern' OpenGL, you can also check what shading language version is supported with glGetString